# Use pivot table cell value to lookup same value in original worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

In my original worksheet of data I've created a VBA script that creates a hyperlink for cell values in one column, column "A".

The displayed text in the column "A" cells after running the script is the original cell value. This script works just fine.

This worksheet data is then used to create a pivot table. Of course the hyperlinks are gone in the pivot table.

What I'd like to be able to do is click on a cell value in the pivot table and have it look for that value in the original worksheet and then open the hyperlink.

I'm using Excel 2013 and the pivot table is the classic pivot table view.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What have you tried so far? This should help you get started: [Worksheet.SelectionChange Event (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194470.aspx). When that event fires, let it run the search (e.g. WorksheetFunction.Vlookup).

Comment: I haven't really tried anything because, frankly, I don't know where to start!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** Let's say this is your source sheet, called `Sheet1`:

**Sheet1**

[image: Sheet1]

Cell `A2` is linking to a website. And your second sheet, `Sheet2` contains a PivotTable of the data in `Sheet1`:

**Sheet2**

[image: Sheet2]

If I understand your request correctly, you want a click on "Peter" in `Sheet2` to open the URL linked in the cell containing "Peter" in `Sheet1`. The way you can accomplish that is by adding the below code to `Sheet2` (right click `Sheet2` in the tabs row and select "View Code").

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Columns.Count = 1 And Target.Rows.Count = 1 And Target.Column = 1 Then
        Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
        Dim SourceRange As Range
        Dim HyperlinkAddress As Range

        Set SourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set SourceRange = SourceSheet.Range("A:A")

        ' Find cell address in Sheet1
        On Error Resume Next
        Set HyperlinkAddress = SourceSheet.Range("A" & _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Target.Value, SourceRange, 0))
        If HyperlinkAddress.Hyperlinks.Count = 1 Then
            ' Click hyperlink
            ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (HyperlinkAddress.Hyperlinks(1).Address)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**Explanation:** The event `Worksheet_SelectionChange` is fired when you select a different cell in an Excel sheet. The above code will first check whether you selected a (and only 1) cell in column A and if you did, find the row number corresponding to the cell containing the value of the cell you clicked but in `Sheet1`. Once it's found, it's verifying the cell contains a link address and - if it does - click it.

Comment: nhee - this looks very promising! And to answer your question, I do want to click on a value in sheet2 and have it look for the corresponding value/link in sheet1. When I get the chance at work tomorrow I'll give this code a shot and post a reply. Again, thanks for the very promising code!

Comment: Ok, that's what this is doing. Please check.

Comment: I'm at work and tried to use the code. After I typed it in, following the instructions given, I get a window that asks for a Macro Name. If I type one in, a new module opens. If I put the code in the new module that opens and try to run it, I get the Macros window again and it asks for a Macro Name. FYI, we can't save macros on our systems; the IT security folks have locked down that feature.

Comment: This will be difficult if you can't save macros... Is it an option to do it on another computer and then transfer the file back to the office computer? You do know that you don't need to __manually run__ the macro, right? It will run itself when you click a cell in column A of Sheet2.

Comment: no, saving elsewhere and transferring is not really an option here. But your last statement was good to read as I did not know that! That's how bad my skills with VBA are!!! Anyway, putting the code in the module and clicking on a value worked like a charm. Thank you so much for your help. Words cannot express my gratitude. If I may, where did you learn these things?

Comment: Learning by doing ;-) -- by the way, could you please follow these steps? [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Thank you.

Comment: your code works wonderfully. how could it be modified to work with a pivot table that is on the same page/worksheet as the original data?

Comment: Change these lines to match the name and structure of that sheet: `Set SourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` and `Set SourceRange = SourceSheet.Range("A:A")`. And make sure you have the code in the right sheet.

Comment: You did change the sheet name and range? What's the name of the source sheet and which column contains the links?

Comment: the sheet name is sheet1 (I did make sure the code was lower case) and the column is A

Comment: Are you getting an error? What happens when you click? Can you add `MsgBox "hello"` to the beginning to make sure the code is executed?

Comment: the message box did not work. does the fact that I've run your previous code in this same sheet have an effect on the second code? because basically that is case with a pivot table step in between that puts the pivot table on the same sheet

Comment: I don't understand that last comment. If the msgbox doesn't show that means the code is not executed. Either there is no code in that sheet or macros are disabled (reopened the file and forgot to enable macros?)

Comment: I'll try to be more clear. I have the original data for which I do the View Code. Into this module I place the hyperlink code above and run that. I then create a Pivot Table in that same worksheet, "sheet1". Here's is where things go wonky. I try to use the code for the hyperlink reference and it does not work. I've tried clearing out the original hyperlink code and placing the reference code in (with the suggested changes) and I've opened up a whole new module for the code. Neither works. I feel he solution is just out of reach...

Comment: Gotcha. Possibly this is the issue, then: `And Target.Column = 1 Then` -- the number must correspond to the column number of the first column of the pivot table, A = 1 etc. This serves the purpose of only executing the code when clicking into that column and selecting a 1x1 area.